# How do I access SharePoint 2019 on-premises list data to Native React mobile app(Not SPFX WebPart)?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, authentication, react, authorization, single-sign-on

I want to access SharePoint 2019 on premises list data and do CRUD operation on it into react native mobile app. How do I do this using REST API(Without sending user name and password - Single sign on with react mobile app and SharePoint on-premises)?

Comment: Which authentication provider is configured for SharePoint web application? (Windows Authentication, ADFS, FBA, ...)

Comment: @Massimiliano Macchia  It's ADFS